# How to pull Connected App Settings for Permission Set

Tags: deployment, metadata, connected-apps, permission-sets

I have a permission set that has connected apps assigned, but I am unable to view them when I pull down the metadata. I've tried using MavensMate and ANT. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

I wondered if this item in the [Summer '17 release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_api_meta.htm) held a clue:

**PermissionSet**

> In API version 40.0 and later, when you retrieve permission set
>   metadata, all content exposed in Metadata API for the permission sets
>   are retrieved. Retrieval includes Apex associated with the permission
>   set, CRUD, and so on. In API version 39.0 and earlier, retrieving
>   permission set metadata returns only the app and system permissions
>   assigned to the permission set. Junction metadata (such as Apex, CRUD)
>   are included only if the metadata for the related component is also
>   included in the package definition.

This does not explicitly state that the junction object between Connected App and Permission set is exposed in the Metadata API. I tried to retrieve PermissionSet and ConnectedApplication to see what metadata came back, using this package.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
      <members>*</members>
      <name>PermissionSet</name>
    </types>
    <types>
    <members>*</members>
      <name>ConnectedApplication</name>
    </types>
    <version>40.0</version>
</Package>
```

In PermissionSet, the object, system and user permissions were returned, but not junctions to a connected app. Oddly, the Metadata API returned "Entity type: 'ConnectedApplication' is unknown," which surprises me given the release notes.

I *have* established that PermissionSetAssignment does not serve as the junction object between PermissionSet and ConnectedApp (as it does for users). I did this by running a SOQL query like this against a connected app known to have a permission set assigned to it:

```
SELECT Id,PermissionSetId, PermissionSet.Name
FROM PermissionSetAssignment
WHERE AssigneeId = '[ID of connected app]'
```

This query returned no results.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little late but I figured out a way to do this.
From the Connected Application object, I pulled the connected application matching an Id (Or whatever you have), then I used the `permissionSetName` field to check for my permission set

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_connectedapp.htm